# Red Dead Redemption region lock

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, red-dead-redemption

At last the game became backward compatible and I wanted to buy it. I was trying to buy it on Xbox.com but MS response was something like: Sorry, we can't complete the action right now. After that I went to amazon and bought the digital prepaid code there. When trying to redeem the code the error occurs:

> Something went wrong
>   Give it another try. If this happens again, let us know by entering the code below at xbox.com/errorhelp so we can investigate.
>   Xbos-0x80150017
>   dd38c006-bf1d-4f2b-91df-d076abd15f10

Is the game region locked?! Can I play it somehow if I already have the code?

Comment: _Red Dead Redemption_ is [not region locked](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200150426-Region-Compatibility-Information-for-Rockstar-Games). Something else must be going on.

Comment: Also, you're not alone in having this issue. Seems like [a ton of people are experiencing the same thing recently](https://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/5574/t/2182754.aspx?pi7962=1).

Comment: Thanks guys, hope someone will answer this someday. The game seems to be great (had no console when it was out), hope to play it!

Comment: Have you tried redeeming the code again? One of the Xbox reps on the forum is claiming that the issues should be resolved now.

Comment: @pushasha I've tried, no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Red Dead Redemption* is not region locked, as detailed in [this Rockstar region-compatibility support page](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200150426-Region-Compatibility-Information-for-Rockstar-Games).

One of the reasons you may have initially encountered issues purchasing the game the other week, is that there was a server-side issue [preventing people from purchasing *Red Dead Redemption*](https://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/5574/t/2182754.aspx?pi7962=1) around the time you posted this question.

As for your inability to redeem the code you bought on Amazon, that may be a different story. The error code you received (`0x80150017`) brings up the following description on the Xbox support site:

> Error 80150017 occurs when trying to download content on your Xbox 360
>
> You see the following error code and message when you try to download
>   content on your Xbox 360 console:
>
> "Sorry, something went wrong. This isn't available for your region, or the file is corrupted, or we don't recognize the format. Find more info by looking 
>   up status code 80150017 at www.xbox.com/errorhelp"
>
> This may mean one of the following:
>
> - The content you’re trying to purchase is not available in your region.
> - Your billing country or region is different from your physical
>     location.

Since we know that the content you're attempting to redeem/purchase *is* available in your region (as it's not region-locked), the error code shouldn't be related to the first potential reason they list. Based on the second reason they list, the error likely means that the region of the Xbox.com site you're redeeming the code on doesn't match that of your console, or that your Xbox account region doesn't match your console's physical location.

If you make sure all of the regions match up, and you're still getting the error, I'm not sure that I (or anyone else on Arqade) will be able to help you further -- you'll need to talk to an official Xbox support representative.

Comment: Thanks, probably you are right: I'm from Georgia, Tbilisi and in the console's location settings the USA is chosen, because there is no Georgia there to choose it.. So it seems that i just can't enjoy the game.

Comment: @0x49D1 I'm looking at Xbox.com, and Georgia is in the full list of regions. Have you tried switching the region on your Xbox live account [using the Xbox.com website](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-account/change-region#5d67cdf2027943c2820a6d09f0aedaf4)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried.. Even contacted MS support, but no luck.. Tho the support said that I should not have a problem with migration (to US) - something is preventing me from doing so. They've explained it as: system physically locked me to Georgia, and RDR was not distributed to Georgia, the game is old and distribution restrictions are same as before.

Answer (score 0):

There are other things you can try:

1. Redeem the code online (and not via the Xbox): https://account.xbox.com/en-US/paymentandbilling/redeemcode (also, try changing the "en-US" to the Georgia region equivalent)
2. Create a new account that is set to Georgia, and again attempt to redeem the code
3. Create a new account that is set to US, and again attempt to redeem the code
4. Obtain a physical copy of the game (and attempt to get a refund via Amazon) - the physical copy will allow you to play via Xbox One

Note that options 2/3 may mean that you must use the new account to play the game.  Furthermore, you may need a separate gold subscription if you wish to play the online elements of the game on the account.